# What is the difference between StatusCode with specific 200 vs OkResult in ControllerBase (.net core web api)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

What is the difference between `return Ok();` or `return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.OK);`?

I want to return status code 200 in my web api controller

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.ok(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Http.ApiController.Ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Technically there is no difference** between the two approaches.

If you want to look at the code of [`OkObjectResult`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/release/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/OkObjectResult.cs) then you will see that the `OkObjectResult` is an `ObjectResult` that sets the 200 status code, which is the default of ObjectResult already.

The only real difference is readability in code and just personal preference It is all about naming and what intention you want to stress.

Answer (score 1):

It's acutally the same thing. `Ok()` is just a controller wrapper method for `StatusCode(200)`.